# change the name for root mails from cron

Tags: cron, root, sendmail

I have two servers that are synchronized with rsync, one is the failover server of the other, so they both have the same name.

Now root mails that are sent to my other account are all named from `root <root@myserver.org>` so I have no easy way of distinguishing from which server they are coming.

Is there a way of changing root mails of the one server to  `root failover <root@myserver.org>`?

My first Idea would be simply to change the first line in `/etc/passwd` to

```
root:x:0:0:root failover,,,:/root:/bin/bash
```

But I am afraid to just to try this. Would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the 'From' text by editing /etc/passwd to receive mail from 'root at failover' instead of just 'root'.

```
chfn -f 'root at failover' root
```

source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP

Comment: This doesn't work with all cron implementations. For example, Debian always sends mail `From: Cron Daemon <root@hostname.example.com>`. Which cron are you using?

Comment: The default cron of which distribution? There are several forks and sets of patches around.

Comment: I use the default cron in an up-to-date debian wheezy. And, yes, it didn't work. the last mail I got was from just "root" again ;(

Answer (score 1):

Your failover system must have some network characteristic that distinguishes it from the real one. Unless you have an especially complex setup, the two servers have different IP addresses. On the recipient machine, check the earliest (last) `Received:` header: this header indicates which machine sent the email (from the perspective of the first hop). Use a procmail rule or other delivery-time transformation mechanism to parse that information into a more visible place such as the Subject: line.